# Possible to put a list into the session in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to pass a list into the session? I need my visitors to have different lists.

I tried `session['mylist'] = mylist` but I get a `UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'thread.lock'> objects` error.

```
mylist = None
if 'username' in session and 'password' in session:
    if not api.user:
        api.login(user=session['username'], password=session['password'])
    userlist = api.user.get_user_list(limit=25)
    mylist = list(userlist)
session['mylist'] = mylist
```

EDIT: Turns out the api didn't return strings at all, but objects. This thread can now be closed.

Comment: What is in `mylist` ... by the looks of things it's not something you really want to be passing to the client.

Comment: A list of strings.. Not a good choice, huh?

Comment: there shouldn't be any problem with a list of strings ... the error is telling you that one of those "strings" is actually a `thread.lock`, not a string.  Can you give us an example of what you are doing (i.e. a code snippet that reproduces the error)?

Comment: I'm using an api to get the list, so maybe that's why it has a `thread.lock` while waiting for the response? Edited OP with code snippet.